# SFTP Access with Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory, sftp, sssd

I'm trying to access through SFTP using an Active Directory user.

I have a RH7.3 machine, configured with SSSD. Sshd_config has some parameters that allow some AD users to login throught ssh. Now I've created a new group in AD (access_ssh_vsftp) with some users and I want access with these users throught SFTP but NOT throught ssh.

SFTP group (**access_ssh_vsftp**) is configured on **sshd_config** (last lines):

```
Match Group "ADNAME\access_ssh_vsftp"
 ChrootDirectory /home/folder/%u
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I've tried with differents "**Match Group**" like **access_ssh_vsftp** or "**access_ssh_vsftp@adname.com**" but it didn't work.

On the other hand, I don't know if I have to set "**access_ssh_vsftp@adname.com**" in AllowGroup section (sshd_config) because if I set it I can access throught SSH and SFTP but, if this parameter does not exist, I can not login throught ssh neither sftp.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If `AllowGroup` doesn't exist, then chance is that you have `AllowUser` somewhere.

Comment: AllowGroup exists and I can login through ssh. It was only a doubt that I had. Thanks